# Attribute directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive

For whatever reason I'm not able to select any of the angular4 tags for this question. I'm using Angular 4.

I've created an attribute directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[SpDatePicker]'
})
export class DatepickerDirective {

    constructor(public element: ElementRef) {
        console.log(element.nativeElement);
    }
}
```

But if I try to use it, I get the following error:

> Can't bind to 'SpDatePicker' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

Usage:

```
<div [SpDatePicker]></div>
```

---

If I change the selector declaration to:

```
selector: '.spdatepicker'
```

and use the following HTML:

```
<div class="spdatepicker"></div>
```

It works fine. I've looked at [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives) and can't see what I'm doing wrong. Can anybody tell me?

I've created a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/YBKaRVIP6aG9SW8kwBHt) demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Please use <div SpDatePicker></div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `[]` for a attribute directive, this will lead angular consider `SpDatePicker` as an `@Input property` of `div`.

---

As commented by @Maximus, you can still use `[SpDatePicker]` by adding an `@Input() SpDatePicker` into your directive.

---

**[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/YlWB8cbFl66aX33pCKmq?p=preview)(for both)**.

Comment: Thank you. I feel stupid now - I didn't notice that they didn't use [] for the actual element in the documentation.

Comment: @john `[]` is normally considered as **property binding**. :-)

Comment: @john, but this way `<div [SpDatePicker]></div>` is possible if you define an input in SpDatePicker with the same name `@Input() SpDatePicker`, then what you tried will work

Comment: @Pengyy, you can add information from my previous comment to your answer

Comment: @Maximus yeah, I forgot about this point.  thanks for pointing this out.